# Como agregar un listener para obtener un token de firebase de un proyecto diferente

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

actualmente tengo un proyecto vinculado con firebase y agregue el archivo de google-services.json y para obtener el token ocupo este metodo:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Get new Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

hasta ahi todo bien obtengo el token, el problema es que quiero obtener el token de otro proyecto de firebase actualmente lo hago asi:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("id_de_otro_proyecto", FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
```

y de esta manera funciona perfectamente el problema es que quiero agregar un listener a ese nuevo gettoken para no crear una clase asyncrona.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deseas realizar , era el método anterior donde defines el Sender Id ("id_de_otro_proyecto"):

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("id_de_otro_proyecto", FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
```

Actualmente no tienes que definir un sender id, ese id y la configuración se encuentra definida en tu archivo de configuración [google-services.json](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=es)

```
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {

        }
    });
```

Si deseas usar el id de otro proyecto deberás descargar el respectivo archivo de configuración [google-services.json](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=es) y volver a construir tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder Jorge, el detalle es que es un proveedor externo y solo tenemos acceso al id del proyecto.

Comment: @SoyPacheco definitivamente les tienen que proporcionar el archivo google-services.json, es importante que este sea descargado desde la aplicación registrada mediante el paquete de la aplicación, para que la aplicación pueda funcionar sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el problema utilizando el método que se menciona [aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) ya que con el método que menciona @Jorgesys es necesario tener el archivo google-services.json y no lo tenemos.

Una vez que configures un proyecto secundario puedes ocupar el listener que como si se tratara de un proyecto primario asi: 
`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary"))`